# How to find the type of symmetric cipher?

Tags: keys, symmetric

How to find the type of symmetric cipher that was encrypted.
I have ciphertext, plaintext, key.

there is a command in openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OpenSSL is a cryptographic API and TLS implementation with command line interface. It doesn't do crypt-analysis or algorithm detection.

You can try algorithms, probably starting with the most used ones. The size of the plaintext, ciphertext and key may also give hints - keysize and blocksize could point to specific ciphers for instance.

I'm not sure if there are open source or commercial analysis tools out there. You could ask the NSA, I would be hugely surprised if they would not have such a tool.

There is a list mentioned on [ReverseEngineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1423/10011) but to me it doesn't give me much hope of finding an actual result.

Comment: This is a good answer in practice. But it should also be mentioned that this problem is impossible to solve in general. I.e., it is only solvable under the assumption that one of a few well known ciphers has been used.